# Get all my comments from other author post - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm having problem get all my comments from other author post and display in my own post.
I made a loop to capture all post from other author and successfully displayed in my own post. Below of each post, I want to display all my comments and filter exclusively for only my comments but the results it shows all comments from other author.

Here is the code I used to capture all my comments inside loop single template:

```
/** This is outside loop to capture my own author email not from within loop which is from other author's post **/
 $MyEmail =  the_author_email();

/** This is inside loop **/
<?php       
$args = array(
        'post_id' => $post->ID,                                        
        'author_email' => $MyEmail,
        /** When I used comment_id it will displays all comments even I used my comment_id taken from outside the loop. Using 'author_email no comments displayed **/               
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :                    
    echo   ($comment->comment_content);
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try function: [get_the_author_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta)

```
$MyEmail =  get_the_author_meta( 'user_email',$post->post_author);

$args = array(
        'post_id' => $post->ID,                                        
        'author_email' => $MyEmail
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :                    
    echo   ($comment->comment_content);
endforeach;
```